# Error condicion variables a, b y c distintos a cero

Tags: java

Parece que algo debo hacer mal en la siguiente condición para comprobar que las tres variables `a`,`b` y `c` son distintas a cero **utilizando expresión booleana**:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 7;
int c = 11;

if(a!=0 && b!=0 && c!=0) {
  System.out.print("Todos son distintos a cero")
}
```

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar la decl,aración de esas variables por favor?

Comment: Tu código funciona pues ya lo he usado, tu único error y que será motivo de cierre es que en la instrucción de **`print`** se hace falta terminarla con **`;`**

Comment: ``;`` al final: `System.out.print("string");`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

como dice el compañero falta ";" después del System.out.print.

Quedaría así:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) 
 {
    int a = 2;
    int b = 7;
    int c = 11;
        if(a!=0 && b!=0 && c!=0){
         System.out.print("Todos son distintos a cero");
        }
 }
```